# Python Dash - Dynamic and Static input options in same callback function

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I need to write a call back function which will have a dynamic input component and a static input component. But putting them together is throwing error.

This is what I have done so far -

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("new_list", "children")],
    [
     #Static Input Component
     Input("clear", "n_clicks"),
     #Dynamic Input Component
     Input(str(i), "value") for i in item_list[['item3','item2','item1']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
     ],
)
###########################################################
## Updated sample working code

import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import callback_context
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dash_table as dt

item1 = ['A','A','B','B']
item2 = ["W","X","Y","Z"]
item3 = ["L",np.nan,'M','L']
item_list = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(item1,item2,item3)),columns=["item1","item2","item3"])

cat_list = item_list.item1.unique()
global itemlist
itemlist = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['item','qty'])
for item in item_list[['item3','item2','item1']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join):
    itemlist.loc[len(itemlist)] = (item,0)

def Add_item(data,data2):
    print("BILLING: Add_item()")
    item_list = dbc.Card(children = [
                        generate_item(data,data2),
                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([
                                dbc.Button(
                                    html.H5("Cancel"), id="cancel", className="ml-auto", color = "danger"
                                )
                            ]),
                            dbc.Col([
                                dbc.Button(
                                    html.H5("Clear"), id="clear", className="ml-auto", color = "info"
                                )
                            ]),
                        ],style = {"width": "71rem"})
                 ],  
                id="modal-body-newitem"
                )
    return item_list

def generate_item(item_list,itemlist):
    buttons = html.Div(children =[
                           dbc.Row([
                                dbc.Button(
                                    html.H5(str('+ ' + a)),
                                    id= str(a),
                                    className="mb-3",
                                    color="primary",
                                    block=True
                                ),
                                dbc.Collapse([
                                        dbc.Card([
                                                dbc.Row([
                                                        dbc.Col([dbc.Button(html.H5(str('+ ' + b)),className="mb-3",color="info",block=True, disabled = True)],width = 10),
                                                        dbc.Col([dbc.Input(type="number", min=0, max=20, step=1,value = itemlist.loc[itemlist.item == b,'qty'],id = b )],width = 2)
                                                ]) for b in item_list.loc[item_list.item1== a, ('item3','item2','item1')].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join).sort_values()
                                        #,dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody(str("This content is for " + a)))
                                        ],body = True, style = {"width": "71rem", "justify": "centre", "align": "centre"})
                                ],id= str("collapse" + a))        
                            ]) for a in item_list.item1.unique()
               ])
    
    return buttons

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CYBORG])
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
server = app.server

app.title="Test"

app.layout = html.Div([
             dbc.Card(
            dbc.CardBody(
                [
                    html.H5("New Item", className="card-title"),
                    Add_item(item_list,itemlist),
                    html.Div(id = 'new_list')
                ]
            )
        )
])


#Item Ctegory List
@app.callback(
    [Output(str("collapse" + i), "is_open") for i in cat_list],
    [Input(str(i), "n_clicks") for i in cat_list]+
    [Input("cancel", "n_clicks")])
def toggle_collapse_category_box(*args):
    trigger = callback_context.triggered[0] 
    print("MYBIZZAPP:toggle_collapse_category_box:  Call - "+str(callback_context.triggered))
    if not callback_context.triggered or trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0] == 'cancel':
        print('MYBIZZAPP:toggle_collapse_category_box: Not Triggered/Cancel')
        global isopn
        isopn = [False] * len(cat_list) 
    else:
        print('MYBIZZAPP:toggle_collapse_category_box: Triggered')
        for i in range(len(cat_list)):
            if cat_list[i] == trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0]:
                isopn[i] = not isopn[i]
                
    return isopn


### Clear item list
@app.callback(
    [Output(str(i), "value") for i in item_list[['item3','item2','item1']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)],
    [Input("cancel", "n_clicks"),
     Input("clear", "n_clicks")])
def clear_item_box(n2,n3):
    trigger = callback_context.triggered[0]
    print("MYBIZZAPP:clear_item_box:  Call - "+str(callback_context.triggered))
    if trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0] == 'cancel':
        print("MYBIZZAPP:clear_item_box: cancel order")
        itemlist = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['item','qty'])
        for item in item_list[['item3','item2','item1']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join):
            itemlist.loc[len(itemlist)] = (item,0)
    elif trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0] == 'clear':
        print("MYBIZZAPP:clear_item_box: clear order")
        
    return [0] * len(item_list)
    

#Menu item list
@app.callback(
    [Output("new_list", "children")],
    [Input(str(i), "value") for i in item_list[['item3','item2','item1']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)]+
    [Input("clear", "n_clicks"),
     Input("cancel", "n_clicks")])
def menu_item_list(*args):
    trigger = callback_context.triggered[0] 
    print("MYBIZZAPP:menu_item_list:  Call - "+str(callback_context.triggered))
    print(trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0])
    if not callback_context.triggered :
        print('MYBIZZAPP:menu_item_list: Not Triggered')
        global itemlist
        itemlist = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['item','qty'])
        for item in item_list[['item3','item2','item1']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join):
            itemlist.loc[len(itemlist)] = (item,0)
    else:
        print('MYBIZZAPP:menu_item_list: Triggered')
        itemlist.loc[itemlist.item == trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0],'qty'] = trigger["value"]
    
    if trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0] == 'clear' or trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0] == 'clear':
        print('MYBIZZAPP:menu_item_list: Clear|Cancel')
        itemlist['qty'] = 0
        
        
    print('MYBIZZAPP:menu_item_list: Item List')
    print(itemlist)
    return ['Total items selected - ' + str(sum(itemlist.qty))]
    



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

If I do not mention the static input component, code works fine. But I need to have the static component as well.

Overall problem that I am trying to work on is - I have dynamic input text boxes, if and when a value is entered in any of these boxes, that value needs to be accounted for and returned as a table. Also, there is a 'clear' button. If clicked, all values should be re-set to default pre-defined value.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? There's nothing inherently wrong with the first `Input` you shared here.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So I am using spyder as my editor - when I include the static component, line for dynamic input is highlighted with message - "Code Analysis - Invalid syntax (pyflakes E) and on the python command prompt I get this error message - ` File "E:\Python\mybiz360\mybizapp.py", line 161
    Input(str(i), "value") for i in item_list[['item3','item2','item1']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for updating with the error. This issue is coming from your list comprehension. When you add the first input, it creates invalid syntax for the comprehension. This should work, though:

```py
@app.callback(
    [Output("new_list", "children")],
    [
     #Static Input Component
     Input("clear", "n_clicks"),
    ] + [
     #Dynamic Input Component
     Input(str(i), "value") for i in item_list[['item3','item2','item1']].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I do not get error anymore. But I am not able to use the static component as well. When I click on the 'clear' button that triggers my static component, nothing happens. I included a print option within the callback `print(trigger["prop_id"].split(".")[0])` to test if the "clear" component is getting triggered, but it is not. Any suggestion on that? FYI - dynamic components are working as expected though.

Comment: This same input ("clear") is being used in another callback and it is working as expected. But not in this callback.

Comment: I have updated a working code for your reference. So when add more items, clear/cancel  dose not clear the full list.

Comment: 'itemlist' should have Qty = 0 for all items, when clear or cancel is invoked

Comment: There's still a lot going on here that's difficult to unravel. The inputs based on the dataframe are super complicated, but they probably don't have to be. I think this could be a good case for using Dash's [pattern matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) to try to simplify things a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have not worked on pattern matching callbacks before, will need to study. Since my initial issue is resolved I will mark this question as closed.